# Onclick и if. вопрос по синтаксису

Tags: javascript

```
onclick="if (typeof zamanux = 'undefined') {document.getElementById('zam').style.right='-75px';};
```

я неопытный... немогу понять где накосячил... подскажите
без if нормально работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде всё правильно написано. А что собственно не так ?

можно еще попробывать так:

```
if (zamanux == undefined) ...
```

или

```
if (zamanux == null) ...
```

Comment: без if блок сдвигается вправо... с if не сдвигается

Comment: спасиб if (zamanux = 'undefined') ... вот так прокатило

Comment: ой, и вправду ... классическая ошибка! ) @AlexWindHope спасибо что заметили